# How can I convert a basic loop into an in-memory array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have some code that works, but I am trying to improve its performance by using an in-memory array. Here is the code that works.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual



    Dim wsBalance As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wsBalance = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Balance")

    With wsBalance

        For i = 4 To 10

           .Range("I3").Value = .Range("J" & i).Value

           wsBalance.Calculate

           .Range("K" & i).Value = .Range("H14982") * -1


        Next i

    End With



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Applicaiton.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

I've tried to make this code work faster by using an in-memory array, but I am doing something incorrect. Here is the code I have for that:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wsBalance As Worksheet
    Dim var1 As Variant, var2 As Variant, var3 As Variant, var4 As Variant
    Dim i As Integer


    Set wsBalance = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Balance")


    With wsBalance

        Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        var1 = .Range("I3")
        var2 = .Range("J4:J" & Lastrow)
        var3 = .Range("K4:K" & Lastrow)
        var4 = .Range("H14982") * -1

        For i = LBound(var2, 1) To UBound(var2, 1)

            var1 = var2
            var3 = var4

        Next i

        .Range("K4:K" & Lastrow).Value = var4

    End With




Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

When I run the code I get the same value pasted into column K. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: In the first macro it looks like you are relying on the worksheet to calculate a result before you copy the result to a different cell. It seems you are missing the calculations that the sheet performs for you in the new macro. The statements in the For loop do not use `i` as an index anywhere so you are repeating the assignment of entire arrays to each other over and over.

Comment: Yes, the loop is contingent on a whole bunch of cells calculating which is what is slowing up the performance.

Comment: In second set of code I would like .Range("I3") to update with a new amount which will allow the calculations to occur. This does not seem to be happening though.

Comment: Meaning the value in .Range("I3") does not change

Comment: If you still have to rely on `wsBalance.Calculate` any benefit from using an Array would be negligible since the vast majority of the processing time happens during the calculation of the sheet. It would likely reduce processing time the most if you did all the calculating in the code instead of using formulas on the sheet. The second macro is accomplishing nothing since there is no calculation happening. It's assigning each cell in `.Range("K4:K" & Lastrow)` range to a single number: `.Range("H14982") * -1`.

Comment: Depending on what else is on that sheet you might get better performance calling `.Range("H14982").Calculate` instead of running the sheet-level `Calculate`